# How to call another scope function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-scope

In AngularJS, I have 2 scope function in the controller,

```
$scope.fn1 = function(){
//do something A
};

$scope.fn2 = function(){
    //do something B
    //I want to call fn1 here.
};
```

If my fn2 want to call fn1, how can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Since both functions are in the same scope you can simply call `$scope.fn1()` inside fn2.

Comment: Fn1() must be declared before call it on fn2()

Comment: @RolandoCC Thanks alot. I was so sure how to call it but this have to declare before was killing me -*-

Comment: @RolandoCC how to declare it ??

Comment: @Melvin just :

$scope.fn1 = function(){
      
};

Comment: I have the same issue. fn1() just isn't being called and I don't understand why.

Comment: @Subjective Effect Make sure you have $scope as the prefix. If you don't it won't get called and you won't get an error (at this writing for the version of AngularJS I am using at least).

Answer (score 3):

```
$scope.fn1 = function() {
    // do something A
};

$scope.fn2 = function() {
    // do something B
    // I want to call fn1 here.

    $scope.fn1(); // this works

};
```

Answer (score -4):

if you are doing same thing inside both fn1 and fn2 you don't want two scope function, use one function for that.

if you need to addition in fn2 then take common thing for out of two functions then call that.

Comment: I think you should show the user how to do what he asks. He may use fn1 not only from fn2, but from anywhere else